# Need help with a script which copies all files from a folder to another based on time stamp

Tags: scripting

I need to supply start time and end time .

i.e I want all files  from 3 am to 6 am on sep 10th
start time:2021091003
end time  :2021091006

Source folder has files as below

> 00:59 file.2021091000.log
> 01:59 file.2021091001.log
> 02:59 file.2021091002.log
> 03:59 file.2021091003.log
> 04:59 file.2021091004.log
> 05:59 file.2021091005.log

expected output in destination folder

> 03:59 file.2021091003.log
> 04:59 file.2021091004.log
> 05:59 file.2021091005.log

Please help.

Comment: How should we get the time associated with a file? Should we parse it from the file name or should we look at the file's last modification time? Also, what operating system are you using? We can't guess, so you need to tell us since the tools available on different *nix systems can change significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [wildcards](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm):

```
cp -t destination/ *202109100[3-5].log
```

or if your `cp` does not support `-t` option:

```
cp *202109100[3-5].log destination/
```

Comment: Please comment when downvoting for unknown reason

Comment: I am getting  --t illegal option

Comment: Do you use double `-` ? I see only a single `-` in front of `t`

Comment: did not use double .

Comment: I'm not aware of any implementations not knowing `-t`. But there is another option, I'll add

Comment: @pLumo [POSIX cp](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/cp/) and [BSD/macOS cp](https://ss64.com/osx/cp.html) both don't seem to have `-t`.